# Error when trying to use update value in Bigquery sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column name called daily_recon I want to update it to 0 where daily_recon is #REF!. I get an error that says the column name daily_recon is ambiguous on the where statement. How do I fix this, below is the sql script? nb: using bigquery

```
UPDATE dataset.table1 SET daily_recon = 0 FROM `project.dataset.table1` 
where daily_recon ='#REF!'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `FROM` clause.  So:

```
UPDATE dataset.table1
    SET daily_recon = 0
    WHERE daily_recon = '#REF!';
```

Note:  It seems strange that you are comparing `daily_recon` to a *string* in the `WHERE` clause but setting the value to a number in the `SET`. Perhaps you intend `'0'` in the `set`.

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon Linoff. for the answer. This has worked I will be converting the data type to float so needed to get rid of the #ref!